# Why is my View not including _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I recently made some changes to my MVC 3 project.

When I run it, the Views dont include any files like Site.css. 
When I debug my Index() ActionController, it jumps directly to the View, withouting including files like _Layout.cshtml. So i just get a View with a white background, no menus etc.

The Global.asax.cs file contains following code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default2", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{page}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Survey", action = "DisplayQuestions", id = "", page = "" }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If the breakpoint in your controller action is being hit the routes may be wrong but that's not a reason for _Layout.cshtml to not load.

A few things to check:

- Is your view using View() and not PartialView() (the latter ignores ViewStart.cshtml and so the _Layout.cshtml).
- Did you move your _Layout.cshtml recently / Have you renamed Shared (or created a SharedController by accident)?
- Does your view include something like this at the top which would deactivate the _Layout.cshtml?

  ```
  @{
      Layout = "";
  }
  ```
- Does your _ViewStart.cshtml still exist with the following code which activates the _Layout.cshtml?

  ```
  @{
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }
  ```

Comment: I still have viewstart, but just today my project stopped loading layout... wth.

Comment: Spot on! My `_ViewStart.cshtml` was missing.

Comment: Strange, in a ASP.NET React project, the views and in pages/ folder, and don't need to explicity import the layout, it is done automatically. I thought it would be the same when the views are in /views folder.

Comment: @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
} commented out. Such a help!

Answer (score 2):

Move your "Default2" route up above your "Default" route.

the Default route is more generic so Default2 should be first

also, inside your views make sure that you're specifying the layout to use

```
@{
    Layout = "yourlayoutpage.cshtml"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It somehow dissapeared :S Works now!

Comment: viewStart should take care of this though.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got rid of the layout property in your index view.

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I know this has been resolved but for me (MVC 5) I had to add this line of code before the regular view displayed its content

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: why a down vote? At least explain before down voting!!